# TSQL Query Inner Selects from Outer Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am working on a dynamic query and I am a little unsure how to accomplish this task. It seems like something that would be common so I will use this as a learning experience.

My Structure has several tables. I have included a few of them for this example as once I can get the base query down, I can add on to it.

In my final query, the `WHERE` clause will be generated dynamically.

Here is a fiddle of my structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b104

In the inner select `c.` you will notice I have a column called `localeID`. I need to be able to query this in my outer `WHERE` clause.

For example, that localeID will link to the `localeCodes` table and from there, I have another table called `locations`. End result would be saying "Show me everything in North America". Well, we know `localeID` 8 = Utah and Utah is in North America (when joined to the locations table).

Here is the query to keep it with the OP:

```
SELECT a.[trainingEventID],
   a.[teTitle],
   a.[teSource],
   a.[teType],
   a.[teMedium],
   a.[teFlag],
   a.[teCreator],
   a.[teCreated],
   a.[tePOC],
   a.[teDirector],
   a.[teTeammateImpact],
   a.[teCustomerImpact],
   a.[teComplexity],
   a.[intID],
   a.[teNeededBy],
   a.[approver],
   a.[approvalDate],
   (SELECT b.[trainingEventID],
           b.[segmentDate],
           b.[nonProdHrs],
           (SELECT c.[segmentID],
                   c.[localeID],
                   c.[teammateCount],
                   c.[leaderCount]
            FROM   BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS c
            WHERE  c.[segmentID] = b.teSegmentID
            FOR    XML PATH ('detail'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('details'))
    FROM   BS_TrainingEvent_Segments AS b
    WHERE  b.trainingEventID = a.[trainingEventID]
    FOR    XML PATH ('segment'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('segments'))
FROM   BS_TrainingEvents AS a
--WHERE c.[localeID] = '8'
FOR    XML PATH ('event'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('events');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about we also join to those two subordinate tables so we can narrow the result set based on your `c.localeID`:

```
SELECT  a.[trainingEventID],
        a.[teTitle] ,
        a.[teSource] ,
        a.[teType] ,
        a.[teMedium] ,
        a.[teFlag] ,
        a.[teCreator] ,
        a.[teCreated] ,
        a.[tePOC] ,
        a.[teDirector] ,
        a.[teTeammateImpact] ,
        a.[teCustomerImpact] ,
        a.[teComplexity] ,
        a.[intID] ,
        a.[teNeededBy] ,
        a.[approver] ,
        a.[approvalDate] ,
        ( SELECT    b.[teSegmentID],
                    b.[trainingEventID] ,
                    b.[segmentDate] ,
                    b.[nonProdHrs] ,
                    ( SELECT    c.[segmentID] ,
                                c.[localeID] ,
                                c.[teammateCount] ,
                                c.[leaderCount]
                      FROM      BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS c
                      WHERE     c.[segmentID] = b.teSegmentID
                      AND       c.segmentID = tesd.SegmentID
                    FOR
                      XML PATH('detail') ,
                          TYPE ,
                          ELEMENTS ,
                          ROOT('details')
                    )
          FROM      BS_TrainingEvent_Segments AS b
          WHERE     b.trainingEventID = a.[trainingEventID]
          AND       b.trainingEventID = tes.trainingEventID
        FOR
          XML PATH('segment') ,
              TYPE ,
              ELEMENTS ,
              ROOT('segments')
        )
FROM    BS_TrainingEvents a
INNER JOIN BS_TrainingEvent_Segments tes ON a.trainingEventID = tes.trainingeventID
INNER JOIN BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails tesd ON tes.teSegmentID = tesd.SegmentID
INNER JOIN BS_LocaleCodes as locale ON tesd.localeID = locale.localeID
INNER JOIN BS_Locations as loc ON loc.location = locale.location
WHERE loc.[location] = 'Arizona'
FOR     XML PATH('event') ,
            TYPE ,
            ELEMENTS ,
            ROOT('events');
```

Comment: That looks very promising. Sadly, I have never thought of doing inner select while also joining the same data but this proves to be a good use case for it. It works with my fiddle so its an acceptable answer :) Ill try and get it into my production procedure and let you know (for what its worth). You had one typo on the second inner join, should be `tesd.` not `tesd=`

Comment: So here is the issue I am running into. This happened to me on my own approach as well so I may have been on the right track all along but now back to this.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/661f8/1 . A trainingEvent can contain multiple segments and each segment can contain multiple segmentDetails. This data needs to be group by the segment because right now, its duplicating each event for every segment. It needs to be Training Event -> Segments (grouped) -> segment details. Does that make sense at all? If you look at the fiddle, you will notice the duplicate data and hopefully what I am trying to do

Comment: How about if you add a condition where the subselects need to equal the JOINed Segment tables?  I have added above.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but it still didn't work for me. This is the part I can never get past :). I'll just keep messing around with it